# Port forwarding windows 7

Tags: windows-7, router, port-forwarding

I need to forward petitions from a laptop connected on two routers. The first one is the Internet router (192.168.1.0/24, WIFI), 
and the second is a VPN router (10.x.x.0/24, WIRED, DHCP relay over untrust network) which is connected to the trust interface.

Internet router > Windows 7 PC > VPN router (trust interf)

How can I redirect the traffic on port 22 from the Internet router to VPN router in Windows 7?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you  just connect the two router together?

Comment: I tried it, but It didn't work.